# Login with Facebook/Twitter on Distributed CMS

Tags: php, facebook, security, content-management-system

Essentially, what I'm doing is writing my login and authentication routines for the CMS I'm developing. I'd like to incorporate the ability for a user to log in using Facebook or Twitter instead of having to type in their username and passwords. Part of the feature is the site owner would be able to turn this feature on and off, depending on their security preferences for managing their site.

I've got the app set up in Facebook and Twitter, though what I'm running into is that the request will only ever be bounced back to one URL, even though I'm intending that the CMS be downloaded and installed on separate domains and run independently from one another.

I've tried setting up a simple service that my CMS can dial home to (which is where the responses have to be funneled to due to Facebook and Twitter policy). Idealistically, my service would retrieve the user's facebook or twitter ID, and output the response data as an XML feed so that my CMS could parse the response and log them in accordingly. The part that I'm snagged on is the feed will prompt the user to login every time, so it seems like the permissions are not where they need to be, or the data just isn't crossing the domains appropriately.

What am I missing here?

Comment: _“I'm intending that the CMS be downloaded and installed on separate domains and run independently from one another”_ – why no separate apps then? Have the person who wants to use your CMS set up their own app, and you have true independence.

Comment: I was trying to avoid the need for people to do that. Simplicity is the goal, but I suppose if it's unavoidable, there's nothing I can do to get around it. I'd still like it to be something that is just already ready to go after they install the CMS.